# HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse firing two calls to the server

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest

Below is a code snippet I am using to post data to a REST based server.  If I start debugging on the server I am seeing two separate requests come through.  What I want to know is why?

My request is failing because of the second call.  If I debug it shows the first request is going through fine, but when I try and read the response on the client side it sends over  new call to the server and that one fails authentication.

Comments inline below where the 2 calls to the server fire off...

```
        string requestUri = "/Service/Contacts";

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(SERVICEBASEURI + requestUri);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AUTHENTICATE, m_AuthenticationKey);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(UTCTIMESTAMP, m_UtcTime.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"));
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(NONCE, m_NonceValue);
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Test-Framework";

        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        string postData = "instance={\"FullName\":\"Altonymous\"}";
        byte[] postDataBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postData);

        // TODO: Add postData to the Payload.  Needs to be done on authorization side as well.
        string requestPayload = GetPayload(requestUri);
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(AUTHORIZATION, requestPayload);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;

        Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        // First call fires off to the server.  I didn't expect it to happen here...
        stream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();

        // Second call fires off to the server.  This is where I expected it to happen.
        using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, httpWebResponse.StatusCode);

            Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string resultString = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(resultString);
        }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you expect the server to have been contacted and a TCP/IP connection opened with it once you've started writing a stream to it?  I'm more confused by GetResponse contacting the server, frankly.

Comment: Honestly, I expected the same thing as you.  However, as I read documentation it let me to believe the reverse is supposed to be the case.  Either way two calls is what's killing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears this is a bug in the Microsoft testing design.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "this is a bug in the Microsoft testing design"?  I have the exact same problem.  What did you do to stop the second from being fired to the server?

Comment: I switched to Ruby on Rails and left that headache behind.  And no I had never used it before.  But I'm glad I switched.

Answer (score 1):

try this~

```
httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 10;
```

Comment: Can you explain what this will do to stop the second event from firing another call to the server?